# How do I unlock my Samsung Galaxy Tab S4?

Tags: samsung

I just got a new Samsung Galaxy Tab S4. I did not set a password in the setup as I did not want one. The tablet timed out and now it wants a password which I don't have.

I have tried all the reset options I can find on Google, but none will take me to the reset screen.

What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into recovery mode and make a complete wipe of the phone. This will remove any password. **WARNING: All your data will be removed too.**

Answer (score 0):

According to [the OP's (now deleted) comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209950/how-do-i-unlock-my-samsung-galaxy-tab-s4#comment269379_209975) (with copyedit),

> I have since found the answer. Shut the tablet off by holding power and volume down for about 45 sec. As soon as the Samsung logo appears, let go of the buttons and reapply with power and volume up until the boot screen appears. Use volume up or down to select which function you want and hit the power button to apply. It might take one or two tries for it to totally do the reset. Follow the directions with the setup.